# Не создаются файлы в кеше synfony2

Tags: php, кэширование, symfony2

Возникла проблема, бьюсь уже не один день. Почему-то перестали создаваться нормально файлы в кэше прокетов на symfony2

Т.е. то прокси файлы доктрины не создались, то клас загрузить загрузчик какойнь-дь не может из самого фреймворка, всегда разные причём. Бывает после удаления кэша он создаётся нормально, а бывает не помогает ника. Пробовал уже и вендор заново переустановить и права все на тысячу раз проверил. Уж не знаю во фрэймворке рыть или может с серваком чего?

Comment: Окружение какое, прод? В проде, насколько знаю, он и не должен ничего создавать, `app/console cache:warm` после любых изменений.

Comment: проверьте права на директорию app/cache

Answer (score 1):

Это частая проблема начинающих Symfony-разработчиков. Вы не пользуетесь ACL. В итоге, права, которые Вы выдаете на папку `app/cache` нигде ничем не наследуются и все дальнейшие изменения внутри папки не гарантируют того, что Ваш консольный пользователь будет иметь те же права на файлы в этой папке, что и пользователь веб-сервера.

Прочитайте внимательно раздел про установку прав на директории в [документации по Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup).

Если же у Вас есть проблемы с настройкой ACL, Вы всегда можете прописать в `app/console`, `web/app.php`, `web/app_dev.php` вручную установку прав на все создаваемые файлы:

```
umask(0002); // 0775
// или
umask(0000); // 0777
```